# Formula to create random date, excluding weekends

Tags: datetime, excel-formula

Can someone please provide assistance with creating a function in Excel to do the following:

- Create a random list of dates (between date 1 and date 2)
- Skip weekends and only use weekdays
- Specify the range between random dates

For example, the above would create x amount of date between date 1 and date 2 with a variance of 12-15 days between each date and only on weekdays.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Dates are numbers, you can start experimenting with `RANDBETWEEN()`, and update your post if you are stuck.

Comment: Hi zx8754, thanks for the help. At the moment I have =RANDBETWEEN(15,20), but this just results in a series of numbers between 15 and 20 (inclusive). If I transfer this to dates starting from date x, the numbers do randomly fall on weekends. I need the numbers to only fall on weekdays and skip the weekends but still maintain the 15-20 randomization based on a 5-day week.

Comment: You can use something like:
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2000,1,1),DATE(2014,12,30))

Comment: @curiosu, you don't use commas, but semicolons. 
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2000;1;1);DATE(2014;12;30))

Comment: @Lvka
You need commas, not semicolomns.

Comment: @Lvka comma or semicolumns in formulas are dependant on your regional settings.

Comment: @zx8754 I guess every day  I learn something new. Thank you for that! I had same List separator set even on different regions (US and EU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To choose a random weekday between two dates A1 and A2, inclusive:
`=WORKDAY(A1-1,RANDBETWEEN(1,NETWORKDAYS(A1,A2)))`

To add a random number of non-weekend days to the previous date, with the previous date being in A1:
`=WORKDAY(A1,RANDBETWEEN(9,11))`
You could put this in B1 and drag down for an arbitrary number of days.

Comment: Hi maybeWeCouldStealAV, the =WORKDAY(A1,RANDBETWEEN(9,11)) works perfectly. Thanks so much  Bec :)

Answer (score 0):

In A1 Cell type this formula it will pull range of 24 years of dates for you.

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(1990;1;1);DATE(2014;12;31))
```

**RIGHT** click with mouse in lower right corner of Cell and pull down or where ever you want and select "Fill Weekdays" from menu that will pop up.

Edit: Forgot to mention you need to format your Cells as Date or you will get ID of dates.